# Creating your own flutter widgets best practice

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to understand the best style for creating your own widgets in flutter, and here are 2 very simplified examples

With the code at the bottom, I can use 1)

```
new SomeWidget("Some title", someFunction);
```

or 2)

```
SomeWidget.widget("Some title", someFunction);
```

or 3) Some other way I'm not aware of

Method 1) feels more correct (if I've not made some mistakes), however method 2) actually has less code (as I don't need to declare the object variables earlier, assuming I don't need access to context), but I'm wary of static methods.

Is 1) preferred, and why ?

```
class SomeWidget extends StatelesssWidget {

  String title;
  Function callback;

  SomeWidget( this.title, this.callback );

  //method 1
  Widget build(context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: callback,
      child: ....some widget
    )
  }

  //method 2
  static Widget widget(String title, Function callback) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: callback,
      child: ....some widget
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Your second version doesn't even need or use SomeWidget. It could be a top level function, making SomeWidget redundant.

Comment: Ignore the pointless edit. After some thoughts it should have been asked in another question, which I made here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-widgets/53234826#53234826. This question should answer yours too, go take a look ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know actual guildelines, but I would prefer something like

```
class SomeWidget extends StatelesssWidget {

  SomeWidget({this.title, this.callback});

  final String title;
  final VoidCallback callback;

  Widget build(context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: callback,
      child: ....some widget
    );
  }
}
```

or you can do like this

```
SomeWidget({this.title = '', @required this.callback})
```

for default values or if some value is reqired

P.S. All this is not guideline - it's just an IMHO )

Comment: Andrey is right with this one. Anyway, If you have a `StatelessWidget` all fields of the Widget should be immutable e.g. final. If the State of the Widget should be able to change, use a `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: You're right, I just missed this moment. Actually, fields in `StatefulWidget` have to be immutable too )

Comment: Oh, I meant fields in the `State` of the `StatefulWidget`.